# I can't figure out these beginner SQL commands?

Tags: sql

I'm using https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all to enter my commands for my intro class. For the life of me I can't get the extended price and move on. Here are the commands I'm supposed to enter:

-Select order number, order date, product name, quantity ordered, and extended price (quantity * price) for all customers (INNER JOIN, AS, calculated field).

-Select order number, order date, product name, quantity ordered, and extended price for customer 2 (INNER JOIN, AS, calculated field, WHERE).

-Select order number, order date, product name, quantity ordered, and extended price for customer 'Around the Horn' (INNER JOIN, AS, calculated field, WHERE).

-Add a new shipper with ID 4, name 'On Time Delivery', and phone '(503) 555 0123' (INSERT).
-Increase prices on all products by 1 (UPDATE).
-Reduce prices on all products by 1 (UPDATE).
-Change the new shipper's name from 'On Time Delivery' to 'On-Time Delivery' (UPDATE, WHERE).
-Delete the new shipper (DELETE, WHERE).

I left off here:

```
SELECT OrderDetails.ProductID as ProductName, OrderDetails.Quantity,
       Orders.OrderID AS OrderNumber, Orders.OrderDate
FROM OrderDetails
INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID;
```

Comment: ProductID as ProductName? The id value is just an integer, it doesn't contain any name.

Comment: W3*ools should know that a table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: I was told to rename that so it would show up as ProductName in the editor's database.

Comment: The name is probably another column in the products table.

Comment: @jarlh: that's the least of the problems of w3fools

Comment: So does anyone know how I join Products into it to get the price??